# Heroku - Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, git, heroku

I'm trying to run  `heroku run rake db:migrate` but I continuously get this error message:

Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
I have seen people say just type in Git Init, but when I type in that, I just get

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /app)
>   Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
>   fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /app)
>   Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
>   fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /app)
>   Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
>   fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /app)
>   Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

Kindly guide me..

Comment: FWIW. I've had the similar error message for my python/django app, which was triggered by a 3rd party module poorly setup.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the behavior AND and warning by exporting `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1`.

Specifically, on Heroku, if you `heroku config:set GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1` the warning will go away.

It's probably because you are building a gem from source and the gemspec shells out to `git`, like many do today.  So, you'll still get the warning `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` but addressing that is for another day :)

My answer is a duplicate of:

- comment [GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM problem when working with terminal and MacFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116015/git-discovery-across-filesystem-problem-when-working-with-terminal-and-macfusion#comment30999809_17498212)
- and copied from my answer in I posted an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326278/879854

Comment: Setting `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1` will turn it `ON` not off. Also this is slightly misleading because while it gets rid of the warning, it doesn't address the issue git is facing. You will need to publish the gem you are sourcing locally. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800074/custom-ruby-gem-in-gemfile-on-heroku

Comment: Disagree . Everything works as described. No need to publish gem locally.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Just type git init into your command line and press enter. Then run your command again, you probably were running git remote add origin [your-repository]